Embedding image attachments in HTML emails from android
I'm trying to send an email from Android with HTML content and image attachments. I also want to embed the images inside the HTML body.
The following works correctly:
        ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = fwrImageUris(...);
        String htmlContent = generateHtmlContent(...);

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject goes here");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlContent, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
    }

However, I also want to embed the images inside the html, similar to the following:
<img src="cid:<cid_goes_here>" width="150" height="150" />

However, as far as I can see, the CID is defined later in the process and there's no control over it or visibiliy that it might be (which makes sense). Is there any way to actually do so after all?
Are there any alternatives to do so without external image hosting? Base64 also seems to be an undesired alternative as it's blocked in many clients.

There's not going to be a good answer for this.  You're sending an intent to start whatever email client the user has on the phone.  That could be Gmail, Outlook, or any of hundreds of random apps installed by the OEM or the user.  They won't all act the same way.  There's not even a promise their email client supports html.  Your best bet is to upload the image and reference the URL, that should work unless the email app doesn't support html emails.
